# How to disable db migration (liquibase migration) from flowable docker images?

Tags: docker, bpmn.io, flowable

I am using Docker images to host flowable. DB driver is postgres. When we start the IDM and REST, it runs liquibase script to create db tables. Since default configuration is drop-create in databaseSchemaUpdate in code base, it is very difficult to scale or even restart docker idm and rest (as it drops db always and creates new). So to tackle this, we are looking to disable db migration and change it to "true" so that it throws error if db version doesn't match. Can someone please share if they have done similar for any Flowable Docker service? It seems to be not working by setting environment variable (i might be wrong in this). 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from Flowable forum here: https://forum.flowable.org/t/disable-auto-creation-of-db-tables/2071/7